# How to create a confusion matrix for one node of a decision tree?

Tags: decision-trees, model-evaluations, confusion-matrix

I am doing past papers for my data science exam and was curious about one of the questions. They ask us to create a confusion matrix by hand for one node of a decision tree.

I understand how to create a decision tree for an entire model, but I am unsure on how to create one for just one variable. Should the entire first row be 0s other than the class A as it should always predict class A or am I missing something.

I have attached the decision tree and the exact wording of the question below. Thanks!

"(iv) Present a confusion matrix for the [leftmost terminal] node."

[image: Decision Tree]

Comment: If the tree had only one node, what would you do? Do same for that node, as if it is the only node

Comment: At least this is what I gather from the phrasing of the question. Unless there have been previous questions which follow another route, which would clarify this question further

Comment: I don't think the other questions are related so I believe 10xAI must be what they are asking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CM is about True Vs Predicted.

*Since only one node is in the discussion which means we will have only one column of "Predicted" but all the possible rows of "True"*

Let's assume 100 samples in the Node. The Node must be classified as "A"

*Below should be the CM - Rows are "True" and the Column is the "Predicted"*
\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
 &A &B &C &D &E &F \\
\hline
A &62 &- &- &- &- &- \\
\hline
B &21 &- &- &- &- &- \\
\hline
C &13 &- &- &- &- &- \\
\hline
D &00 &- &- &- &- &- \\
\hline
E &02 &- &- &- &- &- \\
\hline
F &02 &- &- &- &- &- \\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks! Glad there wasn't something I was missing :)